# Graph traversal problem touching every node exactly once

Tags: algorithms, graph-traversal, search-problem

Is there a name for the problem:

> Suppose you have a connected, undirected graph; find a path that touches every node exactly once.

This is basically the complement of the [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) problem, and the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) without the minimum distance constraint.

I've googled and StackExchange'd and come up dry, though it's possible I just lack the proper vocabulary.

Bonus points if you can point me to an algorithm or a set of requirements for such a path to exist.

---

Edit:  It turns out I had Hamiltonian Path mixed up with the [Eulerian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) problem.  I had looked up both problems about 10 years ago, and evidently got them mixed up in my head in that amount of time.  Then, being sure I knew what a Hamiltonian Path was, I didn't actually read my attached link.  /facepalm

Comment: Why is it the **inverse** of Hamiltonian path? What's the difference between the two problems?

Comment: *Complement* may have been a better word.  The Hamiltonian Path requires you to touch every edge exactly once, touching any particular node as many times as is required.  This problem requires you to touch every node exactly once, ignoring edges you don't need.

Comment: The problem cannot be solved in polynomial time (unless P=NP). If you had an algorithm that is guaranteed to find a Hamiltonian path, given that one exists, in time $\mathit{poly}(n)$, then you could run it on an arbitrary graph in order to decide, in time $\mathit{poly}(n)$, whether it contains a Hamiltonian path: just stop the algorithm after $\mathit{poly}(n)$ steps (and reject), and if the algorithm does halt on its own, check whether the Hamiltonian path that it outputs really belongs to the graph.

Comment: I think that you're thinking about [Eulerian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) paths. The [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) requires you to find a path that traverses each vertex exactly once. It seems to me that this is exactly your problem.

Comment: [A Hamiltonian path visits every _vertex_ exactly once.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path)

Comment: Oh!  I remember looking up Hamiltonian paths about 10 years ago, and apparently got it mixed up in my head.  (And then brilliantly did not actually read the link I posted.)  Thanks all!